# What may be the reason of insertTablet failed reported in container and datanode logs of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

The version of Apache IoTDB I used is 1.2.1, and my container logs and DataNode logs reported this error every half hour: `ERROR o.a.i.d.u.ErrorHandingUtils:61 - Status code: EXECUTE STATEMENT ERROR(301), operation: insertTablets failed`. I also checked the system log, and the record is this: `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.statementExecutionException: 381: [EXECUTE STATEMENT ERROR(301)] Exception occurred: insertTablets`. Since these error messages only reprted failure of writing data, I don't know how should I troubleshoot the possible problem. Anyone can give any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened in Apache IoTDB may because that one of the parameters you write is `null`. You can use arthas to execute `watch` command on the writing interface to see what the abnormal parameters are, and you should be able to know which parameter you need to change. If no relevant exceptions are found, the latest version 1.3.0 of IoTDB has fixed similar bugs. You can also consider upgrading the version first and try the writing process again.